# Modern non-fiction book templates?

Tags: book-design

I used `LaTeX` a couple of decades ago for my thesis and haven't used it since. I'm closing in on finishing my first non-fiction book and am disappointed at the formatting options for my `.docx` files (the commercial book formatting software seems to be targeting novelists). So am looking to `LaTeX` for its robust indexing, toc, figures, etc.

I do want my book to have a modern look. I'm sure that's possible, but am not finding a large repo of templates. E.g., one where there are dozens of nonfiction book templates to choose from. Does such a repo exist?

Comment: What's bad about the standard book-template? // Try a search like https://www.google.com/search?q=latex+template+book . E.g. Overleaf seems to have a plethora of book-templates, and many others, too. // Also, a cover is a work of art. Fonts can be changed and adapted, while the books template is pretty robust, AFAIK.

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks. I did that google search and when through all the book templates at Overleaf and found most of them to be not great from an aesthetics/design standpoint. Mostly they seemed dated or kinda ugly. I'm looking for a simple and clean.

[This one](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/bitume-ou-bocage-zone-a-defendre-lhistoire-dun-territoire-en-lutte/mrskwcmynptj) on Overleaf was the only one I've found so far that was close to what I had in mind. Are there more repos like Overleaf's?

Comment: Ok. However, looking at your link, I don’t see any obstacles to turn class book or koma’s scrbook into the layout, look&feel there. If you think in terms of separating content from form … what’s your point?

Comment: Take a look at the `memoir` class (`texdoc memoir`) which provides many means of designing your publication. It also discusses book and thesis design.